# When I use the plaiceholder plugin to blur images in nextjs, why does it crash when there are more images?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I use the following code to blur the remote images, when the number of images is small it can be executed, but now I have 50 images and the browser gets stuck after the project runs.

what is the best way to optimize it? Is it caused by the plaiceholder plugin or by nextjs itself?

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { getPlaiceholder } from 'plaiceholder';
import { PhotoData } from '../types';

const directory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'data');

export async function getPhotos() {
  const filePath = path.join(directory, 'photos.json');
  const jsonData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
  const photosData = JSON.parse(jsonData).sort((a: PhotoData, b: PhotoData) =>
    new Date(b.date) > new Date(a.date) ? 1 : -1
  );

  const photosProps = await Promise.all(
    photosData.map(async (photoData: PhotoData) => {
      const { thumbnail } = photoData;
      const { base64, img } = await getPlaiceholder(thumbnail);

      return {
        ...img,
        blurDataURL: base64,
      };
    })
  ).then((values) => values);

  return {
    photosProps,
    photosData,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to implement a similar thing, but predict a similar issue and frontend will get messy.  So, I will try to store the hash images in the backend, in my case, using my cms.

If you are using only nextjs, you can try to do that in nextjs backend.
I think you can get the inspiration on how to do that from the below video by Jack Herrington https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfHsIio4aCU&t=803s